# C# reflection control properties parameter count mismatch exception

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a textbox and a datagridview with a custom property that's bool.  I'm using reflection to enable the textbox or datagridview at runtime depending how my custom property is set.  The code loops through each controls properties and if it's my custom property and true then I enable the control.

I'm getting a "Parameter count mismatch" exception on the *datagridview only.* I have found a work around but I'm not sure why it works.  The first foreach loop below throws an exception.  The second does not.

I've done some searching and what I found points to the property being an indexer.  I know it's not and GetIndexParameters().Length for the property is 0 with both control types.  Why doesn't the first example work?

```
    Type type = control.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

    //Exception
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.Name == PropName & Convert.ToBoolean(property.GetValue(control, null)) == true)
            (control as Control).Enabled = true;
    }

    //No excpetion
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.Name == PropName)
            if(Convert.ToBoolean(property.GetValue(control, null)) == true)
                (control as Control).Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (property.Name == PropName & Convert.ToBoolean(property.GetValue(control, null)) == true)
```

You are using `&` instead of `&&` which means that you are trying to execute `GetValue` on *every* property, regardless of the name.

In the second example, you *only* attempt `GetValue` on the matching property, so `GetValue` is never called on the property that throws the exception in the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

You used the single `&` which does not short circuit. This means that regardless of the result of `property.Name == PropName` it will always evaluate the second operand, in this case your `Convert.ToBoolean(property.GetValue(control, null)) == true` statement.

Use the double ampersand `&&` which *will* short circuit and won't evaluate the second operand if the first results in `false`.